# Impossibility of expressing "there are at least n+1 objects" without using existential quantifiers

Tags: model-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. I define the first-order signature $L_n$ to consist of $n$ constants $c_1,...,c_n$ and no relation or function symbols besides equality. In $L_n$, for any integer $m$ between $1$ and $n$ inclusive, it is possible to express "there are at least $m$ objects in the universe" using a $\forall$-sentence, in fact a quantifier-free sentence. I conjecture that for any integer $k$ greater than $n$, it is impossible to express "there are at least $k$ objects in the universe" using a quantifier-free or even a $\forall$-sentence, but rather requires an $\exists$-sentence. Is this conjecture true?

Comment: Are you ruling out mimicking an existential quantifier with $\lnot \forall x \mathop. \lnot \varphi$?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet That's not a $\forall$-sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a standard exercise that $\forall^*$-sentences - that is, sentences of the form $\forall x_1,...,x_n\theta$ with $\theta$ quantifier-free - are preserved under taking substructures: if $\varphi$ is $\forall^*$ and $\mathfrak{A}$ is a substructure of $\mathfrak{B}\models\varphi$, then $\mathfrak{A}\models\varphi$.

This gives an immediate positive answer to your question since every $L_n$-structure has a substructure of size at most $n$.

EDIT: Per your comment, you're actually asking about a weaker property:

> Is there a $\forall$-sentence which is satisfiable and all of whose models have size $>k$?

("$\varphi$ expresses [stuff]" is standardly understood as "The models of $\varphi$ are exactly the structures satisfying [stuff].") The argument above still applies: as soon as we have $k>n$, every "big enough" structure has a "too small" substructure, and so no satisfiable $\forall$-sentence can avoid having "too small" models.

---

Two quick comments:

- Incidentally, the *converse* of the result above (phrased appropriately!) is also true, but definitely harder. If memory serves, Hodges'  model theory book(s) has a good discussion of this and related preservation-characterization theorems. But that's not needed here.
- Your claim that "There are at least $k$ objects" is $L_n$-expressible with a quantifier-free sentence for $k\le n$ is **not** true, at least not according to the standard meaning of "express" (see above): we can have a structure with lots of elements where all the $c_i$s are equal! What you can do is write, in $L_n$, a quantifier-free sentence whose *spectrum* (= set of cardinalities of finite models) consists of all numbers $\ge k$ for each fixed $k\le n$. The argument of my answer also shows that even this weaker result is not achievable with a $\forall^*$-sentence if $k>n$, though, so there is a real distinction between $\le n$ and $>n$.

Comment: Well, what I mean by express "there are at least k objects" by a quantifier-free sentence is, that every model of the sentence has at least k objects, and there are models of the sentence in the first place.

Comment: @user107952 That's not what "express $X$" means though: when you say you can express $X$ by a sentence $\varphi$, that means that the models of $\varphi$ are **exactly** the structures satisfying $X$.

Comment: @user107952 Do you have remaining questions about this?

Comment: Oh, sorry for not accepting the answer sooner.